# Python accessing tuple and changed element with extremely complex logic

Tags: python, tuples

I know python tuple is immutable, yet I need it to change some elements at any means!

this is my list of tuples.

```
x = [
  ('a', '2k'),
  ('t', '664'),
  ('hg', '4f'),
  ('m', '6'),
  ('b', 'ad'),
  ('t', '664'),
  ('a', '2k'),
  ('m', '6')
]
```

I want when any element of a list is matched with tuple's first element then its 2nd element should be changed into `ok` string

for example, the list:

```
ok = ['hg', 'm']
```

If any element of `ok` list exist on the list of tuple, the that tuple first 2nd element should be replaced with 'ok`

```
and most important thing is, then index position shouldn't be changed
```

I am expecting this output below:

```
output = [
  ('a', '2k'),
  ('t', '664'),
  ('hg', 'ok'),
  ('m', 'ok'),
  ('b', 'ad'),
  ('t', '664'),
  ('a', '2k'),
  ('m', 'ok')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
output = [(key, 'ok' if key in ok else value) for key, value in x]
```

**Output**

```
[('a', '2k'), ('t', '664'), ('hg', 'ok'), ('m', 'ok'), ('b', 'ad'), ('t', '664'), ('a', '2k'), ('m', 'ok')]
```

As an alternative for longer `ok` lists you could use a [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
ok = ['hg', 'm']
lookup = { key : 'ok' for key in ok }
output = [(key, lookup.get(key, value)) for key, value in x]
```

**Output**

```
[('a', '2k'), ('t', '664'), ('hg', 'ok'), ('m', 'ok'), ('b', 'ad'), ('t', '664'), ('a', '2k'), ('m', 'ok')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot update a tuple, but you can update the element of a list. Use a list comprehension and check if the second element of each tuple is in the list `ok` as follows:

```py
x = [
  ('a', '2k'),
  ('t', '664'),
  ('hg', '4f'),
  ('m', '6'),
  ('b', 'ad'),
  ('t', '664'),
  ('a', '2k'),
  ('m', '6')
]
ok = ['hg', 'm']
output = [(a, 'ok' if a in ok else b) for a, b in x]
```

Comment: I'd suggest expanding the tuple

Comment: @DeepSpace, what do you mean by expanding the tuple?

Comment: `[(a, 'ok' if a in ok else b) for (a, b) in x]` Clearer and shorter

Answer (score 2):

A simple list comprehension is all you need:

```
new_list = [(a, "ok") if a in ok else (a, b) for (a, b) in x]
```